# SSO with application specific claim roles and authorization

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver3, claims

Here's the situation: I'm trying to integrate SSO into an existing .NET Webform/MVC/WebApi environment using IdentiyServer3.  Because there's no centralized role management, SSO is for identity only.  Each application handles its own role and authorization.  Also can't demand too much changes, so all the IsInrole, Authorize(Role="") and Web.Config role stuff have to work.

The question is: where do I stuff the claim/role?  I tried add it like the following, but then two applications start seeing each other's roles.  Doesn't sound right.

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>  {
    var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
    var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(id.AuthenticationType,
        ClaimTypes.Email, ClaimTypes.Role);

    nid.AddClaim(id.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email));
    nid.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
```

Did I miss something important?  Sorry if it sounds too stupid.  I'm too new to know better, and there's not enough good keywords to narrow it down on the web.

In summary, I need a SSO solution where each client handles its own role claim and authorization.  Thanks

Comment: BTW, I have a CustomClaimPricipal:ClaimPrincipal.  Try overriding IsInRole, that's fine, but doesn't work with [Authorize(Roles="admin")].  Also try creating a CustomAuthorizeAttribute, override OnAuthorize ... without success.

Comment: Thanks for moving the question here.  In the latest round, I created a OwinMiddleware, take context.Authentication.User, create a new CustomClaimPrincipal and stuff it back.  It works.  I have 3 apps in 3 tabs, each gets its own custom claims from DI injected service on every page refresh.  But I'm still not sure if this is the right approach.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait a second, I think this earlier version of [IdentityModel.Owin.ClaimsTransformation](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.Owin.ClaimsTransformation/tree/master/source/Owin.ClaimsTransformation) is exactly what I did.  Mine is not as polished of course.

I just wasn't sure replacing Authentication.User like this is safe.

```
var transformedPrincipal = await _options.ClaimsTransformation(context.Authentication.User);
context.Authentication.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(transformedPrincipal);
```

**Update**:

Ended up customize the ClaimsTransformation middleware above from

```
 public Func<ClaimsPrincipal, Task<ClaimsPrincipal>> ClaimsTransformation { get; set; }
```

to

```
 public Func<string, Task<List<Claim>> ClaimsTransformation { get; set; }
```

feed a ICustomClaimProvider to it, which return a list of user claims by id from database.  Then instead of

```
context.Authentication.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(transformedPrincipal);
```

this

```
context.Authentication.User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "appid"));
```

Now User has two identities, one original, one contains application specific claims.  Seems working well if I understand it correctly.